# Is overclocking worth it?

Tags: overclocking, windows-xp, amd-athlon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I overclock a dying PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/84892/should-i-overclock-a-dying-pc)

I have a (relatively) old computer running WinXP SP3 with an AMD Athlon XP 2800+ processor that I am thinking about overclocking to try to get a few more years out of the computer be for I have to upgrade.
I was wondering if I would be able to get a reasonable enough speed increase to make the overclocking worthwhile?
Also, this would be my first overclocking attempt. Are there any good resources out there for first-time overclockers? (preferably other than websites that are in Russian ;)
Thanks!

Comment: How can a question about overclocking an relatively old desktop PC be a duplicate of overclocking a dying laptop? This is another case of a bossy moderator that is to fed up with himself to read a question he locks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is overclocking worth it?

This really is subjective, and we can't answer such questions. You have to see for yourself, just be careful.

If you get much more speed but your computer seems to be near it's end it might not be worth it...

> to try to get a few more years out of the computer be for I have to upgrade

This is a contradiction to me, overclocking will shorten the lifetime.

Whether the speed increase helps is again subjective and you would have to see that for yourself.

> Also, this would be my first overclocking attempt

Be careful and read enough information, overclocking too far can damage your components.

And it's more like to happen on an old computer as the overheat protection wasn't so well back then...

More information: [What steps do you take when overclocking?](https://superuser.com/questions/17513/what-steps-do-you-take-when-overclocking)